# Set End time on form for a calendar in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, calendar

I am upgrading a calendar from the 2007 template to a 2010 template and found that for 2 years worth of data, nobody set the end time for the events. When I switch over to the 2010 template, none of the events show up on the calendar view unless I manually add the end time. I have tried several different types of workflows in both Nintex and SPD and none of them work.

1. I have tried setting a calculated value column that adds 15 minutes to the start time, then set the End Time to the calculated value, SPD and Nintex workflows error out
2. I tried the several jquery scripts in this forum, none have worked [This one doesn't work](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2009/09/setting-default-duration-for-new-calender-events/)
3. Used the calculated calendar feature in Nintex WF, it changes to the correct time but unable to insert into End Time field

I tried a modified version of #2

```
    // Set the hours to add - can be over 24
  var hoursToAdd = 0;
  // Mins must be 0 or div by 5, e.g. 0, 5, 10, 15 ...
  var minutesToAdd = 5;

  // JavaScript assumes dates in US format (MM/DD/YYYY)
  // Set to true to use dates in format DD/MM/YYYY
  var bUseDDMMYYYYformat = false;

  $(function() {

    // Find the start and end time/minutes dropdowns by first finding the
    // labels then using the for attribute to find the id's
    // NOTE - You will have to change this if your form uses non-standard
    // labels and/or non-english language packs
    var cboStartHours = $("#" + $("label:contains('Start Time Hours')").attr("for"));
    var cboEndHours = $("#" + $("label:contains('End Time Hours')").attr("for"));
    cboStartHours.val("08:");
    cboEndHoursHours.val("17:");
});

// Some utility functions for parsing and formatting - could use a library
// such as www.datejs.com instead of this
function dtParseDate(sDate)
{
    if (bUseDDMMYYYYformat)
    {
        var A = sDate.split(/[\\\/]/);
        A = [A[1],A[0],A[2]];
        return new Date(A.join('/'));
    }
    else
        return new Date(sDate);
}

function formatDate(dtDate)
{
    if (bUseDDMMYYYYformat)
        return dtDate.getDate() + "/" + dtDate.getMonth()+1 + "/" + dtDate.getFullYear();
    else
        return dtDate.getMonth()+1 + "/" + dtDate.getDate() + "/" + dtDate.getFullYear();
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("initEndDateEvent");
```

I'm at my wits end, can the End Time column for calendars be edited in a workflow or script?

Answer (score 0):

What error are the workflows reporting?

Can you run PowerShell on the farm? Would be an easy enough script to loop through and set the field values.